# Why does old english niman from PGmc *nemaną, have "i"?

Tags: etymology, germanic-languages, old-english

Why does old english niman from PGmc *nemaną, have "i" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In late Proto-Germanic, there was a sound change that changed **e* to **i* before a following nasal consonant in tautosyllabic coda position: **b**e**n.da.ną* became **b**i**n.da.ną* because the first **n* was in coda position, but **n**e**.ma.ną* was left alone, since the **m* is in the following syllable.

Later on, a more generalised sound change occurred in some parts of Germania, raising **e* to **i* before all nasal consonants, even if they were not in coda position; this changed **n**e**man* to **n**i**man*.

This latter change probably started in the Ingvaeonic (Anglo-Frisian) period and area, since we see it in both English and Frisian. In Frisian, it is not entirely consistent – often, variants with both /i/ and /e/ are found, such as Old Frisian *nima* and *nema*. In Old English, on the other hand, it was carried out pretty much throughout, and the sequences *en* and *em* were rare in Old English altogether.